# Download Files via FTP NOAA

Tags: python, download, ftp, noaa

I'm trying to download data via ftp from the NOAA website.
This is CPC Global Temperature data. However I am getting a permission error.
What should I do ? please

```
from ftplib import FTP

# ftp://ftp.cdc.noaa.gov/Datasets/cpc_global_temp/  # Dataset path   

ftp =  FTP('ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov') # NOAA ftp
ftp.login() # Anonymous
ftp.cwd('Datasets/cpc_global_temp/') # Dir datasets CPC global Temperature 
ftp.retrlines('LIST')
ftp.close()
```

When I make this code I get this error

```
error_perm: 550 Datasets/cpc_global_temp/: No such file or directory
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Climate Prediction Center data is at:

```
ftp = FTP('ftp.cdc.noaa.gov')
```

Then your code should work as expected.

If you want an example of how to download one of their files:

```
filename = 'tmin.2020.nc'
with open(filename,'wb') as f: 
    ftp.retrbinary('RETR {}'.format(filename),f.write)
```